# NodeJS, ReactJS: Axios post not updating in time

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I have a really strange issue with an axios post request. In a onSubmit function on a react component I have an axios post that sends an UID and retrieves the number of items with that UID in a collection. In my case is items in the basket for the user. I want to be able to then set that number of items to the component state to use it later for validation. For some reason when I call the request and I print the res.data I get the right output which is the number of items currently in the basket for that UID. When I call with setState however it first doesn't change the state. And as I add items in the basket, it gives me the value that I had previously.

```
axios.post('http://localhost:5000/basket/check', {uid : UID})
    .then(res => this.setState({basket: res.data}))
    .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      })

    console.log(this.state.basket);
    if (this.state.basket < 4) {
        this.props.addBasketItem(basketItem);

    }
```

That is my code. For example I set the basket item in the state 0. When the function gets called first two times the console.log(this.state.basket); prints 0. Then 1,2,3,4 as items get added. But the number of items in the basket is always 2 more which is really strange. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: you need async and await are you doing this in componentDidMount() ?

Comment: not necessarily.  promise chaining is a perfectly fine thing to use here.

Comment: onSubmit(e) function for a button so after the button gets pressed there isn't no rerender

Comment: *Everything* that needs to wait for the API call to be complete needs to be in a `.then` or after an `await`, otherwise it may happen before the data comes back. In your example, the `console.log` is not inside the `.then`.

Comment: Did my asnwer make sense?

Comment: the await async worked so I just used that I'm sure the other ones would've worked but I would've had to change code around so I stuck with the simple solution, thanks all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since setting of state is async you should use callback function in after setting state in order to be sure that only after state is set, you can use it with the freshest data. Try this...

```
checkBasket = () => {
  const { basket } = this.state;
  if (basket < 4) {
     this.props.addBasketItem(basketItem);
  }
}

axios.post('http://localhost:5000/basket/check', {uid : UID})
    .then(res => this.setState({basket: res.data}, () => this.checkBasket())
    .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      });
```

Answer (score 0):

As I understand you want to access the state right after you set it,  we can accomplish this with setState callback.

```
  submitHandler = () => {
    axios
      .post("http://localhost:5000/basket/check", { uid: UID })
      .then(res =>
        this.setState({ basket: res.data }, () => {
          console.log(this.state.basket);
          if (this.state.basket < 4) {
            this.props.addBasketItem(basketItem);
          }
        })
      )
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  };
```

A better solution to this would be using componentDidUpdate  lifecycle.

```
  submitHandler = () => {
    axios
      .post("http://localhost:5000/basket/check", { uid: UID })
      .then(res => this.setState({ basket: res.data }))
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  };

  componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
    console.log(this.state.basket);
    if (this.state.basket < 4) {
      this.props.addBasketItem(basketItem);
    }
  }
```